# raspberry pi 4 cannot detect usb signal from UPS

Tags: raspberry-pi, usb-device, ups

I am trying to connect a Vultech UPS1050VA-PRO  to my new raspberry pi 4 via the usb cable provided, but it does not show up in the lsusb output (I tried connecting it with both usb 2.0 and 3.0 ports of my raspberry pi 4).
I have also tested all the usb ports connecting a usb thumbdrive and they are
all working fine.
Instead when I try connecting the UPS cable to an old raspberry pi 2
lsusb can detect it normally (see below)

where did I go wrong?
Thanks in advance

### info from the tests on raspberry pi 4 with raspbian buster

```
$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$ # no change when connecting the usb cable

$ uname -a
Linux rpi4 5.10.63-v7l+ #1459 SMP Wed Oct 6 16:41:57 BST 2021 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

no entry in /var/log/messages related to that usb cable

=============== =============== =============== ===============

### info from the tests on raspberry pi 2 with raspbian jessie

```
$ echo before connecting UPS usb cable ; sudo lsusb
before connecting UPS usb cable
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1058:1003 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 1000 GB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
 
$ echo after connecting UPS usb cable ; sudo lsusb
after connecting UPS usb cable
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0925:1234 Lakeview Research 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1058:1003 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements 1000 GB
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
$ 
$ uname -a
Linux myrpi2 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

entries in /var/log/messages when the usb cable is plugged in

```
Nov  3 01:27:55 myrpi2 kernel: [210930.891008] usb 1-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
Nov  3 01:27:56 myrpi2 kernel: [210931.038954] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=0925, idProduct=1234
Nov  3 01:27:56 myrpi2 kernel: [210931.038974] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Nov  3 01:27:56 myrpi2 kernel: [210931.038985] usb 1-1.5: Product: UPS USB MON V1.4
Nov  3 01:27:56 myrpi2 kernel: [210931.038995] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Љ
Nov  3 01:27:56 myrpi2 kernel: [210931.055863] hid-generic 0003:0925:1234.0002: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [Љ UPS USB MON V1.4] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0
Nov  3 01:28:27 myrpi2 kernel: [210962.083218] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 6
```

Comment: Looking at [this page](https://productz.com/en/vultech-ups1050va-pro/p/o8g3Y), I'll hazard a guess that this is JAPCJ (just another piece of Chinese junk). They offer no details for "Connectivity" except **USB** which is completely useless. You might look at [`nut`](https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/), or do a [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=linux+nut+UPS&atb=v278-1&ia=web) to learn if your UPS is supprted.

Comment: I have tested the UPS link with an  Ubuntu laptop  and `nut`: it is working fine
(except for the same problem [addressed in this post](https://www.mail-archive.com/nut-upsuser@lists.alioth.debian.org/msg10317.html)  that I mean to address later).
Correct me if I am wrong: `nut` cannot work with a device that is not identified by `lsusb`

Comment: I can't correct you because I don't know. I fooled around with `nut` a few years ago & I recall that the main issue for my case was that much of the "vocabulary" used between a UPS and the software is proprietary; i.e. it worked, but not completely. I quit using it when APC released a "Linux version" of their PowerChute app.

Comment: Many thanks anyway for your help - I have to apologize because I was wrong: in [this comment](https://github.com/networkupstools/nut/issues/640#issuecomment-445214697) I can read that
`0925:1234` is actually a dummy/catch-all code (I should have been warned by the too-simple "1234" product ID). The correct way to request information via `lsusb` is  by specifying the vendor ID and the triple debug flag

`lsusb -vvv -d0925:`

So in the end I discovered that a specific nut _driver_ is still needed for this vendor :-(

Comment: Sounds like you've learned something - which is always a good thing. You should consider submitting an answer to your question - it will help someone else. **P.S.** When you reply to someone in a Comment, you need to add their handle to the beginning of the comment. But that's not necessary when it's their question or answer.

Comment: @sigmud please could you share how you got this working on the PI 4. I have exactly the same issue, UPS doesnt show up in lsups. Would really appreciate some detail of how you fixed this?